# Datagridview and vertical scrollbar c#

Tags: c#-2.0

How to programatically determine that vertical scroll bar is showing for a particular datagridview at run time. Please help me with code in c#.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to tweak sizing behaviour also, so if the data gridview resizes, adjust the scroll bar hight if it does not have any rows to scroll.